# Uploading and storing file with Laravel

Tags: file, laravel

I am using Laravel `illuminate/html` and I am trying to upload an image file and store it in `/public` in the laravel installation folder. I have got the image from the request:

```
$img = Request::file('img');
```

How can I store it in the public folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in your controller:

`Request::file('img')->move(base_path('public/uploads'));`

Or if you wish to specify a generic filename or change filename

```
$newfilename = str_random(32) .time();

 $ newfilename = $newfilename. ".". Request::file('img')->guessClientExtension();



 Request::file('img')->move(base_path('public/uploads'), $newfilename);`
```