# how to get file object laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-6

I send file with form like this

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="images[]" multiple enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
```

but in controller on `$request->all()` I get only file name

```
"images" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "just-before-hit.png"
  ]
```

How to get file object to store it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading and storing file with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691429/uploading-and-storing-file-with-laravel)

Comment: No, it will work when I get file object in controller, but I have only name and when I try to make like this $file = $request->file('image'); it return null

Comment: You need to use [`$request->file('images')`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#files).

Comment: dd($request->file('images')); -> null on view side

Answer (score 5):

You can get the file object using **`$request->file('NAME')`** or using **`$request->FILEINAME`**. for more information visit the official laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files) and here is the example for you.

```php
$files = $request->file('images');
foreach($files as $file){
    // here is your file object
    dd($file->getClientOriginalName());
}
```

You'll need to add **`enctype="multipart/form-data"`** to your form. Otherwise, file upload won't work properly.

Comment: $request->file('photo'); return NULL to me

Comment: because you are uploading file as named `images` see the updated code. As you are uploading multiple file, you have to iterate through to get file objects

Comment: I delete multiple upload and now try to upload only one file and it return null
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" enctype="multipart/form-data" />

Comment: if you have single file use `$file = $request->file('image')` also don't forget to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form

Comment: add `enctype="multipart/form-data` to the form not inside the input tag. I tried it works

Answer (score 0):

You can get file name and of of its property with this `$request->file('Name of your input field')`. For more information please check laravel documentation.[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files)

```
$file = $request->file('Name of your input field');
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Comment: $request->file('by_name') return null

Comment: #Дима Свободин first upload file and then click on submit button then check and `dd($file)` it will return to you object of file.

Comment: Done, but it still return  null

Comment: #Дима Свободин can you share your code here. How you are getting file name. Thanks

Comment: and also check in your form tag is included with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` not only to input but also to `<form enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

If that can help

add in your controller : `use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;`